# How to set ajax data value in data-percent progress bar in php?

Tags: php, ajax, mysqli

code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#source").change(function(){
            source = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"source":source},
                url:"get-source.php",
                success:function(data){

                    show = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#total").html(show.total);
                    $("#sources").html(show.sources);
                    $("#progress1").attr('data-percent', 5);
                    $("#progress1").data('percent', 5);
                }
            });
        });

        $("#tech").change(function(){
            tech = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"tech":tech},
                url:"get-tech.php",
                success:function(data){

                    show = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#per_tech").html(show.per_tech);
                    $("#techno").html(show.techno);
                    $("#progress2").attr('data-percent', 5);
                    $("#progress2").data('percent', 5);
                }
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>

<select name="source" id="source" class="form-control">
    <option>Select Source</option>
    <?php
        $sql = "select name from source";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$rows['name']."'>".$rows['name']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>
<select name="tech" id="tech" class="form-control">
    <option>Select Technology</option>
    <?php
        $sql = "select name from course";
        $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
            echo "<option value='".$rows['name']."'>".$rows['name']."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</select>

<div class="bar-chart">
    <div class="chart clearfix">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="bar">
                <span class="percent"><div id="total"></div></span>
                <div class="progress" id="progress1" data-percent="75">
                    <span class="title"><div id="sources"></div></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <div class="bar">
                <span class="percent"><div id="per_tech"></div></span>
                <div class="progress" id="progress2" data-percent="">
                    <span class="title"><div id="techno"></div></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code I have created percent progress bar. Now in my ajax file i.e. get-source.php and get-tech.php I have calculated percentage through query which working fine and also show in progress bar but the problem is when I change any value from dropdown it shows percentage but I am unable to pass a dynamic value to data-percent through ajax. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: share your #source and #tech html code and get-source.php and get-tech.php php code

Comment: but where is #source because if there is onchange event it should be dropdown or something?

Comment: I have edit in my code where you can see #source dropdown and #tech dropdown @BhumiShah

Comment: Check out the ```xhr``` property of Ajax calls, ```$.ajaxSettings.xhr()``` and its ```onprogress``` events!

Comment: @omkara: i checked your code on my local and it is passing value to data-*.

Comment: Try with this : $(document).on('change','#source',function()

Comment: I have tried you code @BhumiShah its working but problem is that when I change dropdown value it show me percentage but does't genrate bar and after when I inspect element it generate bar what was the problem is this ?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap progress bar?

Comment: I am not using bootstrap @BhumiShah

Comment: thn What are you using for progress bar?

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax code, you have to set the data-percent value dynamically.Right now it's only pass the `$("#progress2").attr('data-percent', 5);` every time.
It's should be like this,

```
$("#tech").change(function(){
        tech = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{"tech":tech},
            url:"get-tech.php",
            success:function(data){

                show = JSON.parse(data);
                $("#per_tech").html(show.per_tech);
                $("#techno").html(show.techno);
                $("#progress2").attr('data-percent', show.per_tech);//here you can pass the value

            }
        })
```

Comment: issue is not dynamic value, the data-parent is not changing

Comment: isnt success just called once, when the function succeeds? You need to continually grab the data, not just when the transfer succeeds.